# Java Direct Reference Hash Value

Tags: java, perl, hash, hashmap

In perl a hash looks like

```
%last_name = (
    "Ward",   "Cleaver",
    "Fred",   "Flintstone",
    "Archie", "Bunker"
);
```

And there is the option to directly reference a key, in order to retrieve it's value.

```
say $last_name{Archie}; # Bunker
```

I've been looking for some time now and have found no option to achieve the same thing without creating a method to do it.

Is there a way to directly reference a key in a Java hash to retrieve it's value?

Comment: there is already a method in map interface called get(key) -> returns value. What do u want>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` as follows.

```
HashMap<String,String> lastName = new HashMap<>();
lastName.put("Ward","Cleaver");
...// The rest of your names
```

Then to directly reference a key, you can call `lastName.get("Archie");` which will return your `"Bunker"`.

Comment: I'm not sure why my searches didn't present this answer. I guess I need to learn to understand Java docs.

Answer (score 1):

In java we have a lot of implementation of hash many of them implement Map interface. Depends on your need you have to pick the right one. HashMap is the most general. 
Before that it was hashtable which all methods are synchronized. There is also a TreeMap or for concurrency purposes ConcurrentHashMap.
Check all Map implementation if you want to get a detailed knowledge of the topic.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html